# Servicestack UnAuthorized

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." when using the servicestack utils to call a remote API. It requires auth basic or JWT. Calling the same API from PostMan works fine.

```
var json = $"http://localhost:5000/API/Proxy/IsValidGuidForSetupDevice?Guid=82870f2ca21148739bff0854b306415c".GetJsonFromUrl(requestFilter: webReq => { webReq.AddBasicAuth("DevAdmin", "test1"); });
```

if i call below with the same user pass in a browser window. i get a valid connect and a bearer token back. The user\pass is good.

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/credentials?username=DevAdmin&password=test1&format=json
```

AM I missing something in  request filter of the Util? Maybe I should be calling it differently and using a bearer token?

Update after tracing with fiddler

I moved the code into a unit test in the same project as the servicestack service. Just to remove any variables.
Fiddler shows me that : `No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present. WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Basic realm="/auth/apikey"  GET http://localhost:5000/auth`

Raw View

```
HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
DNT: 1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:5000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ss-opt=perm; loginLevel=none; X-UAId=2; ss-id=XPc7ivcCrXuN5tEWwARG; ss-pid=TDeEjUiKck82foJGLGtX
```

Playing around with it. I can get it to login by calling the URL directly with user and pass. The i get the bearer token back and I am able to pass it.

```
var json = $"http://localhost:5000//auth/credentials?username=DevAdmin&password=test1".GetJsonFromUrl();
                var o = JsonObject.Parse(json);
                var token = o.Get<string>("bearerToken");
                var jsonr = $"http://localhost:5000/API/Proxy/IsValidGuidForSetupDevice?Guid=bc464658d6a640febbd53ba17c351919".GetJsonFromUrl(
                    requestFilter: webReq => { webReq.AddBearerToken(token); });
```

I still can't call this in one call with auth headers and I still don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever diagnosing different behavior between HTTP Requests of different clients you should inspect the raw HTTP Traffic between the different clients using a HTTP Packet sniffer like [Fiddler](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp) or [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/), or if the request is made from a browser you can use their built-in Web Network Inspector tools.

Seeing and comparing raw HTTP Request/Responses are the best way to identify how the requests differ.

The [AddBasicAuth()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/828b2c2d1add0e07130be8021219dbbe740c02f9/src/ServiceStack.Client/WebRequestUtils.cs#L144) extension method lets you add HTTP Basic Auth to the Web Request, if you want to send the JWT Token instead you would use the [AddBearerToken()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/828b2c2d1add0e07130be8021219dbbe740c02f9/src/ServiceStack.Client/WebRequestUtils.cs#L162) method instead.

Comment: I am calling my servicestack service from another hosted service. I am missing why the auth does not work with webReq.AddBasicAuth("DevAdmin", "test1");  I cannot get a bearer token until it authenticates. From a disconnected service i cannot use the json service client, which works fine. I will look at wireshark later today, thanks

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @SteveColeman Can you provide the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers for the same successful request made by Postman and below it the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers made by the HTTP Client so we can clearly see and compare the differences between the 2 requests.